# HTML/VanillaJS modal not opening when triggered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m having an issue with my code where the `delete-data-modal` won’t open when the event is triggered. The other two modals (`target-weight-modal` and `new-weight-modal`) open perfectly fine, and even give the `body > div` a blur and no pointer event. I have checked everything but I can’t seem to find anything. The console log shows that it detects being clicked on delete all data. I have tried testing the code in different browsers and devices, but the issue persists.

Here is a link to the live version on CodePen: https://codepen.io/seanrw93/pen/WNYgyJW

(Note: You'll have to create a "new profile" to enter the main page, just enter any dummy data to pass through that)

Here are the relevant snippets of code that handle the opening of the `delete-data-modal`:

```js
const showModal = e => {
  const modalSelector = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-target")
  const modal = document.querySelector(modalSelector)

  if (modal) {
    modal.style.display = "flex"
    document.querySelector("body > div").style.pointerEvents = "none"
    document.querySelector("body > div").style.filter = "blur(5px)"
  }
}

const hideModal = () => {
  const modals = document.querySelectorAll(".modal")
  modals.forEach(modal => modal.style.display = "none")
  document.querySelector("body > div").style.pointerEvents = "auto"
  document.querySelector("body > div").style.filter = "none"
}

//Event listeners

const modalTriggerButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".modal-trigger")
modalTriggerButtons.forEach(trigger => {
  trigger.addEventListener("click", showModal)
})

const cancelButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".cancel-button")
cancelButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", hideModal)
})
```

```html
<button class="modal-trigger" data-target=".target-weight-modal">Update</button>
<button class="modal-trigger" data-target=".new-weight-modal">Update</button>
<button id="delete-button" class="modal-trigger" data-target=".delete-data-modal">Delete all data</button>
```

In this code, an event listener is added to all elements with the class modal-trigger (I have also included the process for hiding the modals for added clarity), which includes the `#delete-button`. When the #delete-button is clicked, the `showModal` function is called, which sets the display of the `delete-data-modal` to “flex”, which should make it visible (but alas it does not).

Comment: Your delete modal seems to be retaining its `display: none` property from the definition of `.modal` in your CSS. That's why it's not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard HTML element `dialog` is probably best. Close the dialog with `HTMLDialogElement.close()`.

```js
document.querySelector("dialog").show();
```

```html
<dialog>Hello World</dialog>
```

Comment: Never knew about the dialog tag, works like a charm! That's just made future projects a bit easier for me, thanks!